# Process and return output based on element level

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform where the output is returned as xpaths for each element in the xml.

Here is my sample xml

```
<NodeRoot>
    <NodeA class="3">
        <NodeB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">
            <NodeC abc="1">103</NodeC>
            <NodeD>103</NodeD>
        </NodeB>
    </NodeA>
    <NodeA class="1">
        <NodeGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">
            <NodeC name="z" asc="2">103</NodeC>
        </NodeGroup>
    </NodeA>
</NodeRoot>
```

My XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
    <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name(.))"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me the below output

```
/NodeRoot
/NodeRoot/NodeA
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeB
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeB/NodeC
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeB/NodeD
/NodeRoot/NodeA
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeGroup
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeGroup/NodeC
```

The xpaths are returned but the order in which they are returned is not what I want. Currently, the order is parent followed by all its child. What I want is that the order is in a way that I get results based on depth of nodes. So first root (level 0) should be returned followed by its immediate children (level 1 elements), followed by level 2 child nodes and so on.

Expected outcome

```
/NodeRoot
/NodeRoot/NodeA
/NodeRoot/NodeA
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeB
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeGroup
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeB/NodeC
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeB/NodeD
/NodeRoot/NodeA/NodeGroup/NodeC
```

So basically

```
All level 0 elements
All level 1 elements
.
.
.
All level n elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of a recursive template process all elements sorted by the ancestor count:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="//*">
           <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name(.))"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyyiVhh

A simple `<xsl:apply-templates select="//*"/>` would select all elements inside the document for processing in document order, however with the nested `<xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)"/>` the processing order is changed and the ones with the lowest ancestor count are processed first. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Applying-Template-Rules which says "The selected set of nodes is processed in document order, unless a sorting specification is present" and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#sorting which says "When a template is instantiated by xsl:apply-templates ..., the current node list list consists of the complete list of nodes being processed in sorted order".

Comment: Thanks this works. One clarification though ... when I debug the xslt, I can see that the transformation happens level wise, but from my understanding, first the xpath is created and then it is sorted based on the position. But how does the transformation change the order of output? A bit more explanation would be great.